# Identityserver 4 reading "X-Forwarded-Proto" header for hosting behind reverese proxy

Tags: identityserver4

After finding out that ASP.NET Core Module acts as a SSL terminator and thus always hosts on http, my question is how to propagate coming from a https address properly into IdentityServer. If you have set the headers `X-Forwarded-Proto` or `X-Forwarded-Schema` with the value https, should this not be picked up? From what I could tell from your `BaseUrlMiddleware.cs` code you set the `SetIdentityServerOrigin` from reading `Httpcontext.Request.Scheme` which behind ASP.NET Core Module will always be http. Since all of your discovery endpoints etc are based on this value from `GetIdentityServerBaseUrl` they will also have a http schema. Please correct me if I am wrong or have missed a setting for this in IdentityServer 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost - IdentityServer relies on whatever is set for the host/protocol etc - at this point in the pipeline.

Behind a load balancer you typically have some middleware in the pipeline before IdentityServer that re-writes those values according to your deployment.

See here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384

Comment: Thank you @leastprivilege for your answer. I still struggle to get the `UseForwardedHeaders` middleware to pick up on my X-Forwarded-Proto headers which have both "https" and "http" values set so I guess I have missed something. When I manually set `context.Request.Scheme = "https";` IdentityServer picks up on that and generates the endpoints with the https schema as you describe. But for now I can continue with my IdentityServer implementation and host it with SSL. Thank you for the great work with IdentityServer 4!